# Java: How do I retrieve a string from a full text search in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, full-text-search

**Edit 4: the problem came from using the string name of the column instead of the column number as indicated below by nuzz**

I've been searching all day and can't figure out how to get a full text search to return a string. It works fine when I type it directly into the mysql command prompt and also works fine if I just use SELECT  username FROM user_info; but I get nothing with this.

```
String result = "";
String request = "SELECT username FROM  user_info WHERE MATCH (username) AGAINST ('themanager');";

    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(request);

    while (rs.next()) {
        result +=  rs.getString("username") ;
        result += "\n";
    }
```

Edit 1:
Here's the code for the table:

```
    Create table user_info ( username varchar(16),
                             password varchar(16),
                             email varchar(16),
                             PRIMARY KEY(username,email));
     ALTER table user_info add FULLTEXT(username,email);
```

Sorry I'm still new to this and have no clue how to copy the code from desc user_info without posting a print screen.

Edit 2: oops wrong code, same problem though.

Edit 3: Just figuered out how to copy the desc. The output gives me all the users in  the database for SELECT username FROM user_info;. I haven't a clue about the specifics of my database system just in that its a default install of mysql.

```
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| username        | varchar(16) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| password        | varchar(16) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| email           | varchar(50) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Can you please do a 'desc' on the table user_info and show us what the column types are?

Comment: Why can not you copy the out put of the result of desc ?Your prepared statement looks correct, whats the error that you are getting. Also post the result for select username from user_info; what RDBMS are you using and how are you executing this sql statements e.g desc meaning are you using squirrel or sqlplus etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this works for fulltext search. Heres what I ran. First I inserted into the database (via mysql console):

```
insert into user_info values('themanager', 'password', 'email@test.com');
```

Once I had that I ran:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TestMysql {

    private String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
    private String user = "root";
    private String password = "password";
    private String dbClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private String query = "SELECT username, email FROM  user_info WHERE MATCH (username, email) AGAINST ('themanager' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";


   @Test
   public void test() {

    try {

        Class.forName(dbClass);
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection (dbUrl, user, password);
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while (rs.next()) {
            String username = rs.getString(1);
            System.out.println("FOUND: '" + username + "'");
        } //end while

        con.close();
    } //end try

    catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


  }

}
```

That printed:
    FOUND: 'themanager'

Try that. Let me know if it fails. If it does, it could well be a connection issue

see: http://www.petefreitag.com/item/477.cfm for more info about FULLTEXT querying

Comment: This example does not use fulltext at all :( this is just an example

Comment: THANK YOU. The problem is coming from using username instead of 1. Too bad I'm never getting those 23 hours of my life back. I'm done with mysql. @shahzeb the code works fine reinserting it with a full text search.